# Converting images of different types to PDF

Tags: command-line, bash, pdf, conversion, convert

I have a few hundred image files. This consist of files of multiple type like 1.png 2.jpg 3.png and so on. I want to create a PDF from these images without changing the order of pages. The number in the image name must be used to preserve the order of pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), you could use a script like that

```
TMP=`mktemp -d`
for img in `ls`; do
    convert "$img" "$TMP"/"$img".pdf
done

convert $TMP/*.pdf merged.pdf
```

EDIT: I saw now a similar response. The only thing that this script adds is merging all the files in only one pdf.

Comment: Actually I used pdfunite at the last line as convert is blurring the images

Answer (score 2):

You could create a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.jpg; do
  convert ./"$f" ./"${f%.jpg}.pdf"
done
```

EDIT:  Source - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29869/converting-multiple-image-files-from-jpeg-to-pdf-format

Comment: OP said that there are multiple extensions like jpg and png, not only one. And you could just write that command in one line instead of creating a script file for it.

Comment: I missed that...I'll have to pay closer attention, apparently